# App Signing Expo app for submit to Huawei App Gallery

Tags: react-native, expo, huawei-developers

I have an [Expo](https://expo.dev/) [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/) app, which I have successfully submitted to AppStore and PlayStore.

However, I need to submit it to [Huawei App Gallery](https://appgallery.huawei.com/).

The step I'm stuck is the "App Signing" where I need to provide certificates.

[image: Screenshot]

**I don't know how to get the `certificate.pem` and `encryptedPrivateKey`** to submit my aab file.

I used `expo fetch:android:upload-cert` and got `app_upload_cert.pem`, but I'm lost on `encryptedPrivateKey`.

Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using expo, run `expo fetch:android:upload-cert`, and the .pem file that you receive can be used in the Huawei app store: at the 'app signing' section, select the option 'Let AppGallery Connect create and manage app signature for me', click browse and select the '.pem' file you just received, and submit. Done!

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that you refer to [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-appsigning-releasedapp-0000001051818319#section124794955812), use the following command:

`java -jar pepk.jar --keystore test.jks --alias test --output=output.zip --encryptionkey=034200041E224EE22B45D19B23DB91BA9F52DE0A06513E03A5821409B34976FDEED6E0A47DBA48CC249DD93734A6C5D9A0F43461F9E140F278A5D2860846C2CF5D2C3C02 --include-cert`

This is the [App Signing Operation Guide video](https://mos-vod-drcn.dbankcdn.cn/P_VT/video_injection/7F13463AB/v3/942838481192717267746424576/MP4Mix_H.264_1920x1080_6000_HEAAC1_PVC_NoCut.mp4) for your reference.

You could click [here](https://infocenter-en.dra.agchosting.link/interactive/iteach.html?language=en_us#c943f69e_8ee6_fb19_3861_27937201a702) to try out.